# Why doesn't Add Web Reference use the schema targetNamespace specified in the wsdl

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, web-services, visual-studio

I have 2 sets of webservices I need to call from C#. Both these group of webservices  come from the same provider & both share one complexType which exists in both the wsdls.

This is what the complex type defn looks like

```
<wsdl:types>
    <schema targetNamespace="http://abc.com/ws/myutil" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <complexType name="mytype">
            <sequence>
                <element name .....
                <element name ....
                <element name .....
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </schema>
    .....
</wsdl:types>
```

The above complex type exists in both the wsdls and the targetNamespace for the type mytype is the same in both the wsdls.

This doesn't cause any issues in `java`.
I use `Axis` for generating the stubs and the `class` for the type mytype is written in a directory `com\abc\ws\myutil` And it it's put in a `package` `com.abc.ws.myutil` as specified by the targetNamespace attribute in the wsdl.

So if I want to call only webservices from the 1st wsdl, I run axis on the first wsdl & generate the classes and then create the jar.

If I want to call only webservices from the 2nd wsdl, I run axis on the 2nd wsdl & generate the classes and then create the jar.

If I want to call webservices from both the wsdl, I run axis first on the first wsdl & then the 2nd wsdl & then create the jar.

Running Axis on the 2nd wsdl overwrites the mytype.java class file generated in com\abc\ws\myutil. But this doesn't matter because the class file generated for mytype.java from the first wsdl is identical to the one generated from the 2nd wsdl. The combined jar I create contains only one mytype & it can be used with webservices from both the wsdls.

However, this identical scenario gives me problems in C#. I add a webreference for the first wsdl URL, it puts the generated classes in the first namespace & then when I add a webreference for the 2nd wsdl URL, it puts the generated classes in a 2nd namespaces.

***So I end up with 2 mytype classes in 2 namespaces.***

So my questions is why doesn't `Add Webreference` use the `targetNamespace` specified in the wsdl? Is there a way for me to make it do that, so that I have just one mytype class?

Have the same issue with ASP.NET VB programs also.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - What is ASMX & why do you think I am using it - I haven't even heard of it.

Comment: You are using "Add Web Reference", which is part of the legacy ASMX technology, so-called because the services used a .asmx file extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the command-line tool `wsdl.exe`, you can use the `/shareTypes` switch:

> /sharetypes
>
> Turns on type sharing feature. This feature creates one code file with
> a single type definition for identical types shared between different
> services (namespace, name and wire signature must be identical).
> Reference the services with http:// URLs as command-line parameters
> or create a discomap document for local files.